# Access denied on MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have granted all privileges to username:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db . * TO  'website_user'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Trying to access database which is in `yy.yy.yy.yy` from `xx.xx.xx.xx`:

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -u website_user -ppassword -h yy.yy.yy.yy my_db > test.sql
```

But still getting below error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'website_user'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

I also checked firewall. Nothing is preventing to run this query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `flush privileges`?

Comment: I restarted `mysql`. And also tried `flush privileges`

Comment: make sure that password doesn't have any shell metachars, like a `$`, e.g. `-pfoo$bar` isn a password `foo$bar`. it's the password `foo` followed by an undefined shell var `$bar`.

Comment: @MarcB: Password is alphanumeric with small and capital characters.

Comment: What is `-ppassword`? it is just `-p`.

Comment: @sємsєм you can pass the password directly after the argument

Comment: It is not secure to reveal the password and It is not like the OP regarded. @MarcHoH

Comment: Have you tried to login with the root user? Just to rule out any server configuration or what not

Comment: Have you made sure you have configured MySQL to accept remote connections from xx.xx.xx.xx ??

Comment: @apesa: if it was a network level trouble, it'd be "connection refused". access denied means that the TCP handshake completed, and the client sent a login request to the server, which then came back as access denied.

Comment: I have created new user with same privileges and it's working now. But, something messed up with old one. Don't know what..

Comment: @RonakPatel:  In the GRANT statement you posted, it looks like there's extra spaces. I'd expect that statement to throw an error. To get the statement processed, it would need to be **`ON my_db.*`** with no spaces  immediately before or after the dot.

Comment: You are not passing a password. either add a space between -p and password or use -password="YOURPASSWORD".

Comment: @SITDGNymall Actually not. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password): *`--password[=password], -p[password]` [...] If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password*

Answer (score 0):

Have you also run the following query:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

That is required to make the new permissions to take effect.

Comment: It's true that changes to the mysql privileges tables applied with DML operations (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) do not take effect until a FLUSH PRIVILEGES (causing MySQL to re-read the privileges tables.) But with the (newer) GRANT, REVOKE. et al. syntax, the changes take effect automatically, without requiring a separate FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement.